# REACT - ¿Còmo puedo detectar cuando un string hace un salto de linea por ser muy largo?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

me gustarìa que me ayudaran a ver como podrìa hacer que cuando un string sea muy largo y haga un salto de linea, se muestre algo como "...", la idea es evitar que haga un salto de linea y se mantenga todo en una sola linea.

[image: string con salto de linea por ser muy largo]

y me gustarìa que cuando el string sea muy largo, se vea con "..." al final, para que no haga salto de linea:

[image: Asì es el string deseado cuando este sea muy largo.]

```
import * as React from 'react'

interface Props {
  isExpanded: boolean
  onClick: () => any
  title: string
}

export const DropdownTrigger: React.SFC<Props> = ({ isExpanded, onClick, title }) => (
  <div className={`dropdown-trigger ${isExpanded && 'is-active'}`}>
    <button
      aria-controls="dropdown-menu"
      aria-haspopup="true"
      className="dropdown-button dropdown-button__trigger button is-radiusless is-fullwidth"
      onClick={onClick}
    >
      <span className="dropdown-trigger__title">{title}</span> /*impresion del string*/
      <span className="icon">
        <i className="fal fa-angle-down" />
      </span>
    </button>
  </div>
)
```

donde "title", es el string que se està mostrando. Espero puedan ayudarme, gracias!

Comment: Lo puedes lograr con css hay un propiedad que se llama `text-overflow: ellipsis;`.  En tu div/span estableces tu width de la medida que tu quieras, tambien tendrias que usar `white-space: nowrap;` para que no haga el salto de linea y tambien `overflow: hidden;` para que desparezca el texto que sale del div/span, puedes crear una clase para que sea reutilizable

Comment: lo voy aintentar @Isaac! gracias por tu sugerencia!

Comment: Ha funcionado bien, gracias @Isaac !